# Are there advertent mistakes?

Tags: meaning

A source says this:

> There are two distinct forms of negligence: advertent (conscious) and inadvertent (unconscious).

(From ["The Distinction between Conscious Negligence and Recklessness"](http://www.lareau-law.ca/article-consciousnegligence.html) by François Lareau.)

Are there also advertent and inadvertent mistakes?

Comment: Sorry! I found it not in Wikipedia, but just in Internet. OK. What difference does it make? Couldn't it be in Wikipedia? Doesn't Wiki explain everything including some odd legal terms?

Comment: @slava bakis : I noticed you made a comment five minutes ago, but you haven't responded in any way to the two answers you have on the table.  Regarding the heroine example, while it's generally opined that trying heroine is a huge mistake, rarely is trying heroine inadvertent, not unless surreptitiously drugged, but then it wouldn't be a person's own mistake.

Comment: Well, if we go real deep into it, then, according to Dr.Freud, there are no inadvertent mistakes at all. Once his little grandson slipped on ice and fell. Grandpa Sigmund, before he even helped the poor child to his feet, asked, "What did you slip on this ice for?"

Comment: Of course. There's also plenty of effable phenomena.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of common definition, which may not be the definition used in some specialized and colloquial contexts, a 'mistake' is not usually if ever considered 'conscious', that is, intentional. Mistakes are 'inadvertent' and 'unintentional'. However, notice that a 'mistake' may be deliberate and thus 'conscious': I've knowingly made deliberate 'mistakes' in order to facilitate learning--for example, in chess, to learn how the 'mistake' or, more accurately, the 'error', might be exploited. Deliberate, or conscious, 'mistakes' however, draw on a dual understanding of 'mistake'; what may be considered a 'mistake' in a limited, special sense may at the same time be considered a productive strategy with a broader reference.

Comparing definitions supports the contention that the usual understanding of 'mistake' is 'unintentional error'. First, a common definition of 'mistake':

> 1. An error or fault resulting from defective judgment, deficient knowledge, or carelessness.
> 2. A misconception or misunderstanding.

[mistake. (n.d.) *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved January 15 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mistake .]

None of 'defective judgment', 'deficient knowledge', 'carelessness', admit of being *consciously done at the time of the "error or fault"*. Nor are 'misconception' or 'misunderstanding', as types of error or fault, *conscious*.

There may be, however, a legal burden on citizens to remedy the 'defective judgment', 'deficient knowledge', or 'carelessness' *before the error or fault* takes place. It is in this sense that 'negligence' may be conscious; a secondary 'negligence' may be considered conscious because before an error or fault of 'defective judgment', etc., in short, before a 'mistake' has been committed, a primary *duty* of cultivating sound judgment (thus avoiding 'defective judgment'), acquiring sufficient knowledge (thus avoiding 'deficient knowledge') or exercising due care (thus avoiding 'carelessness') has been *neglected*.

Other definitions of 'mistake', from *Collins English Dictionary*, *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary*, and *The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus* (see [*The Free Dictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mistake)) do not significantly deviate from the definition presented in the *American Heritage Dictionary*. On the contrary, those definitions support the contention that mistakes are usually if not always considered inadvertent and unintentional:

> mistake ... refers to an **inadvertent** deviation from accuracy, correctness, truth, or right conduct.

(*Random House*)

> An act or thought that **unintentionally** deviates from what is correct, right, or true ....

(*American Heritage Thesaurus*)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no symmetry between negligence and mistakes. Negligence can be advertent, which means, one is deliberately remiss in his/her work. But a mistake is always inadvertent because otherwise it's not a mistake but sabotage, subversive activity, etc. I saw a movie, though, the title of which I don't remember, where a young man, a son of aristocrats, who was trying to pass for a plebeian in the aftermath of the French revolution, deliberately made mistakes in his college essays. Those were advertent ones!

Comment: Is it a mistake to believe that the Bible condemns homosexuality? It is a mistake and a deliberate and advertent one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are conscious mistakes.  People consciously screw up all the time.  People realize that what they're doing is a mistake, but in the inertia of events, they keep on plodding forward into that mistake.  Often, by the time one realizes something is a mistake, it's too late to change course, or some other emotion overrides to keep them committed to their mistake, like pride or a need for approval.

Example:

> Someone tries heroin and gets addicted.  They've been taught all
>   their lives not to even try heroin because it's instantly addictive
>   and instantly destroys peoples lives.  Yet knowing all that doesn't
>   stop them.  And how often do you hear people who have been caught up
>   into heroin addiction later say, "You know, I knew it was a huge
>   mistake when I did it, but I went ahead and did it anyway?"

The complexity of the human condition certainly allows for a person to consciously and even avoidably make an mistake.  I don't think the term "inadvertent mistake" is at all redundant, not innately.

Comment: where is your example from?  What source?

Comment: @michael_timofeev : My example is listed under the word "example."  My reasoning speaks for itself.  Incidentally, you didn't downvote the response that actually doesn't provide an example, or, for that matter, a source.  And that response is by the asker himself!

Comment: You said so.  It was downvoted exactly 10 minutes ago, which is exactly when you left your comment.  It's not rocket science.  Also, I've gone ahead and corrected the example's spelling mistake of "heroin" so as to not distract you further.

Comment: @michael_timofeev : All people make typos.  I try to catch them, but nobody's perfect.  I don't know what "sorry for the crux pun" refers to, but if I wrote it, then it's a typo.  Such mistakes tend to arise out of editing.  They come from changing what I said, and then having vestiges of what I said before inadvertently remain.  The best writers, published writers even, make mistakes.  That's why they have editors.  I see a comma fault, a misspelled word, and the outright misuse of a word in your last message, but that doesn't negate the truths you speak.

Comment: @michael_timofeev : Oh, that's brutal!  Having that happen would have hung with me, too.

Comment: I'd like to be a writer, too.  My problem is flow.  I edit and reedit.  I can't seem to let go enough to get out a streaming narrative.  By the way, did the alcoholism help?  It seems like it would have at the very least provided source material.

Comment: @michael_timofeev : I hear what you're saying.  Were it merely reworking my writing after the fact, then maybe.  But it's so much more than that.  I stumble right at the gate.  It seems that there has to be an initial abandon that I can't eke, a time in which I, as a writer, just blow everything out in a single stream of consciousness.  That's where I always trip.  Imagine how a faerie is caught by having to count salt thrown before him.  It's the same with me and words.  It's my downfall.  It makes me a better editor than writer. I do appreciate your encouragement, though, and I still do try.

Comment: Just write something and get it on paper...anything...then start working with it...all of my students complain about the same thing.  Make a skeleton and then start building it up.  Write a few sentences.  Don't judge them.  Write a few more, then put it away.  Judge it the next day and then take away or add.  Melville didn't write the first chapter of MD in one flowing experience of writerly bliss, but had to wrestle with it and write a lot of crap before he had something to edit.

Comment: Use this site as a practice ground.  Focus on a few answers and make em good and Polish em and use the upvotes as feedback whether you're on track or not .

Answer (score 0):

'Advertent' is a recognized word (with dictionary definitions) but both rare and not commonly understood correctly and is not the antonym of 'inadvertent'

'Inadvertent' means unplanned, not intended, unintentional, mistaken.

'Advertent' is a rare word means giving attention, heedful, not the opposite of inadvertent.

There are lots of common words that have negative prefixes, where if you remove the prefix the remaining word is either nonexistent or very rare and is not necessarily the opposite. A short list of such words is:

[dejected
discombobulate
disgruntled
dismantle
disheveled
impetuous
impinge
indomitable
ineffable
misnomer
nonchalant
nonplussed
unnerved](http://blog.dictionary.com/debunk/)

Comment: @JEL oops...that was a Freudian slip. Editing...